# Mongoose.connect() is not working and connecting

Tags: database, mongodb

MongoDB. connect() is not working what am I doing wrong? While trying to connect my mongoose to nodejs I got this error, importing part is okay and const connection with async and wait for the function is also okay, and try and catch, console log also shows a little bit of issue, I think useNewUrlParser,useUnifiedTopology part is wrong??

```
const Connection = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const URL = `mongodb+srv://visco_blog:VISCOblog@123@blog.gttqj.mongodb.net/VISCO_BLOG?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

    await mongoose.connect(URL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log("Database connected successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while connecting to the database ", error);
  }
};

export default Connection;
```

Comment: What's the error? And can you double check the connection string, I see you have two "@" symbols.

Comment: Error message is needed to debug this further